# Not able to authenticate via internal DNS

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, sharepoint-2010

When I installed Sharepoint on my server, I gave the internal DNS to access the Sharepoint internally (by DNS Manager), but when I am trying access the Sharepoint by DNS sharepoint.abc.com then it is asking for credential when I am giving the credentials it is not getting validated and same credential screen is getting popped up again and again.

When I am giving the IP address instead of DNS then everything is working fine.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you disabled the LoopbackCheck in the registry on each server in the farm? If not, follow the instructions in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/926642 and see if that helps.

You may also want to check that the appropriate alternate access mappings and IIS bindings are configured for the farm.